# How to prepare and hydrate Relay state?

Tags: relayjs

I want to fetch queries server-side and then hydrate [relayjs](/questions/tagged/relayjs) Store when the client-side application loads. Relay documentation currently does not mention what are the building blocks required to build and hydrate its state.

Answer (score 2):

We need three things:

- create Relay store
- populate Relay store with the desired state
- serialize Relay store and pass it to the client

A Relay store is handled by Relay Environment. This means that in order for us to populate Relay store with queries, we have to execute them in the context of a Relay Environment, e.g.

```js
import { Environment, Network, RecordSource, Store } from 'relay-runtime';

export const createRelayEnvironment = (apiUrl: string): Environment => {
  const recordSource = new RecordSource();
  const store = new Store(recordSource);

  const network = Network.create((operation, variables) => {
    return fetch(apiUrl, {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: operation.text,
        variables,
      }),
      headers: {
        'content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: 'POST',
    }).then((response) => response.json());
  });

  return new Environment({
    handlerProvider: null,
    network,
    store,
  });
};
```

Then all you need to do is run a query and serialize the Relay Store, e.g.

```js
const relay = createRelayEnvironment('https://contra.com/api/');

const appPreloadResponse = await fetchQuery<AppPreloadQuery>(
  relay,
  appPreloadQuery,
  {},
  {
    fetchPolicy: 'store-or-network',
  }
).toPromise();

const htmlHead = `
<script>
  window.RELAY_RECORD_MAP = ${stringify(relay.getStore().getSource().toJSON())};
</script>
`;
```

On the client-side, you simply need to create Relay Environment using the earlier serialized state, e.g.

```js
export const RelayEnvironment = new Environment({
  network: Network.create(fetchQuery, subscriptionHandler),
  store: new Store(
    new RecordSource(window.RELAY_RECORD_MAP),
  ),
});
```

And that's it!